# Display all / Update (custom) registered .Net assemblies (RegAsm)

Tags: c#, .net

I am registering many custom .Net RTD server DLLs for Excel (Real-Time Data Feed)
Every time I change a single coma in the code I have to rebuild and redeploy (register) that darn dll.
The fact is, when I change the assembly name from *`ASSEMBLY_XXX`* to *`ASSEMBLY_YYY`* and register it using RegAsm, the former one is still registered (if not explicitly unregistered) and the new one is added on top. This sucks as Excel get mixed up between assemblies when the same classes are exposed via COM.
Moreover, Sometimes, even unregistering old assembly / re-registering new one with the same name (after code change and rebuild) I still get old assembly's output, not the new one. Weird. **(Issue 1)**
So, I got it all mixed up and I would like to explore registry for all of the newly registered assemblies to clean up the mess **(Issue 2)** (*My gramma used to say : "Nothing Good happens after 2AM". Guess that goes for code too...*)

I welcome any positive advice on both issues (among the *"Booh"* 's I am getting used too)
PS : The reason why I change assembly names is duplicating code templates to create new Servers with different behaviors

**EDIT :** 
*Precision : I am using "ProgId" Tag for COM Exposition, and when I change that value and the desired output and redeploy, Calls to former ProgId's result into new ProgId's output.
I really think there is some confusion here in Assembly recognition by third parties.*

Answer (score 2):

I've used [VB Type Library Registration Utility](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/utilities/Type_Library_Registration_Utility/article.asp) from vbAccelerator to clean up similar messes in the past.

Also with your first issue; I recall having seeing this before. The COM registrations are the same and the assembly is in the same location but has been rebuilt with changed functionality. If your client application had previously accessed the assembly before you changed it, you don't observe the new behaviour, but the old. It's as though the .NET framework caches your assembly when it creates the COM callable wrapper; in fact I suspect this is exactly what is happening. Try restarting your client application to invalidate that cache. This is entirely conjecture and opinion.

Comment: It will show the type libraries that are registered that enable .NET assemblies to be consumed by COM applications. I've used this to work with such registrations for assemblies written in C#. It's only that the utility is written in VB, its functionality deals with all COM registrations.

Comment: Link dead, now at http://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/tlb/vbregtlb.htm

Answer (score 0):

After you unregister and then register your dll using resasm, it is best if you use PowerShell to **resetiis**. That should do the trick.